# Excel formula for product detection and price insertion

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’m not so advanced in excel but i would like to ask something, if i have a product in let’s say cell “A2” and would like for cell “B2” to automatically detect the product in cell “A2” and put in a price how do i do it?

Comment: vlookup() or index() with match()

Comment: Some examples: [VLOOKUP()](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D+vlookup) , [INDEX()+MATCH()](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D+INDEX+MATCH) --> Research more =)